# Json post to MVC controller with Parameters

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, json, post

Can't seems to figure out why this is not working. I can't get the parameters to post to MVC controller method:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<input id="Button1" type="button" value="button" onclick="CallMethodone()" />

<div id="result"></div>

<script>

    function CallMethodone() {

        var detailsURL = '/Testdrive/Methodone';

        var request = {
            'parameterOne': "test one",
            'parameterTwo': "test two"
        };

        $.ajax({
            url: detailsURL,
            contentType: "applicaton/json",
            type: "POST",
            data: JSON.stringify(request),
            dataType: "json",
            success: successFunc,
            error: errorFunc
        });

        function successFunc(response, status) {
            //alert(data + " " + status);
            $("#result").text(response.result);
        }

        function errorFunc(xhr, status) {
            alert("error");
        }

    }

</script>
```

And my controller method is like this:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Methodone(string parameterOne, string parameterTwo)
    {
        return View();
    }
```

parameterOne or parameterTwo do not have any values in them.

UPDATE:

[image]

Comment: Nope don't need it. It goes into the controller method but no parameters are passed to it; they are both null.

Answer (score 0):

you can do the following

```
var parameterOne = 'test one';
var parameterTwo = 'test two';
$.ajax({
    url: '/Testdrive/Methodone?parameterOne='+parameterOne+'&parameterTwo='+parameterTwo,
    contentType: "applicaton/json",
    type: "POST",
    success: successFunc,
    error: errorFunc
});
```

or try this:

In code: data: JSON.stringify(request)... remove JSON.stringify,

Should look like:

data: request,

Another detail is its object.

```
var request = {
     'parameterOne', "one test"
     'parameterTwo': "test two"
};
```

In it you put 2 parameter, then in its method you have to get two also.

```
public ActionResult Method (String parameterOne, String parameterTwo)
{
     return View ();
}
```

Look at the result:

http://tinypic.com/r/r0t2z8/8

Comment: is there a way NOT to use parameters inside the URL ? Using the var request = ... way how I showed?

Answer (score 0):

You should create a class for the parameters, try this:

```
[Serializable]
public class Your_Class_Name {
  public string parameterOne {get; set;}
  public string parameterTwo {get; set;}
}
```

At the Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult Methodone(Your_Class_Name parameters)
{
  // Badass code here
}
```

Hope it works =D

Comment: they are still null. I think somehow there is a setting to enable Json data when posting to controller and it is not enabled. Looking it up how to do that.